# Can somebody help we draw following complex figure using tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

Can somebody help we draw following complex figure using tikz?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) This is not a "do it for me" kind of site. Please, provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) in order to show people what you have tried so far and what is your actual problem.

Comment: The lower figure is just a table. You can print it use `tabular` or `tabularx` environment. This might be helpful https://www.latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/tables/

Answer (score 5):

I can't help you with TikZ, but here is an effort in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html).  I've only done the first bit so far

[image]

Here is the source. Compile with `mpost`.

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";
def ? = infont"pcrr8r"scaled.9
rotated 2 normaldeviate enddef;
beginfig(1);
    -z1 = z2 = 100 right; z3 = z2 rotatedabout(z1, 61);
    path t; t = z1 -- z2 -- z3 -- cycle;
    drawoptions(withpen pencircle scaled 2);
    draw t;
    draw for i=1, 5, 7, 2.2, 4, 8: point i/3 of t shifted (normaldeviate, normaldeviate) -- endfor cycle;

    z0 = 1/3 (z1 + z2 + z3);
    label("text1"?, 1/3 (point 5/3 of t + point 6/3 of t + point 7/3 of t)); 
    label("text2"?, 1/3 (point 7/3 of t + point 8/3 of t + z0)); 
    label("text3"?, 1/3 (point 7/3 of t + point 5/3 of t + z0)); 
    label("text4"?, 1/3 (point 4/3 of t + point 5/3 of t + z0)); 
    label("text5"?, 1/3 (point 0/3 of t + point 1/3 of t + point 8/3 of t)); 
    label("text6"?, 1/3 (z0 + point 1/3 of t + point 8/3 of t)); 
    label("text7"?, 1/3 (z0 + point 1/3 of t + point 2.2/3 of t)); 
    label("text8"?, 1/3 (z0 + point 2.2/3 of t + point 4/3 of t)); 
    label("text9"?, 1/3 (point 2.2/3 of t + point 3/3 of t + point 4/3 of t)); 

    label.bot("text"?, origin);

    picture brk; brk = image(draw origin {dir 40} ... {dir 82} 2(5, 15) withpen pencircle scaled 2;
    draw origin {dir -30} ... {dir -84} 2(6, -13) withpen pencircle scaled 2;);

    z10 = point 2 of t shifted -(50, 30);  draw brk shifted z10; label.lft("text10" ?, z10);
    z12 = point 0 of t shifted (-16, 27);  draw brk shifted z12; label.lft("text12" ?, z12);
    z11 = point 3/2 of t shifted 36 right; draw brk reflectedabout(up, down) shifted z11; label.rt("text11"?, z11);

endfig;
end.
```

(PS. Don't take this too seriously...)

Comment: May you edit your answer to provide an exactable code? (\documentclass....)

Comment: @hesham As it says in the answer: "compile with `mpost`"...

Comment: @hesham follow the link at the top if you want to learn more about Metapost.

Comment: I see, never tried before!

Comment: I enjoy the literalness of this answer.